Typescript mapped type with different key types applying value type to all values
I have two key types OneOf and FeildType to differentiate between the two types I have the following type but it ended up merging the member types.
interface TypeMap {
    [key: number]: FeildType
    [key: string]: OneOf
}

I tried merging the two keys into one member like this
interface TypeMap
    [key in (number | string)]: key extends string ? OneOf :
                                key extends number ? FeildType :
                                never
}

But that also resulted in the two types being merged.
Is there any way I can have this type:
interface TypeMap {
    [key: number]: FeildType
    [key: string]: OneOf
}

Without it merging the two member types?

• The word is "field", not "feild"; you might want to [edit] it so it's not a distraction. • Currently this isn't a [mre] because we don't have definitions for FieldType and OneOf. If those types aren't compatible with each other in the right way, then your multiple-index-signature type is invalid. Please provide definitions for these types.

I just figured out that I can achieve this with this kind of type
type ParentType = FeildTypeMap | OneOfTypeMap

interface FeildTypeMap {
    [key: number]: FeildType
}

interface OneOfTypeMap {
    [key: string]: OneOf
}


It isn't clear to anyone but you that this solves the issue, because only you know what FieldType and OneOf are. Please edit the question to give us that, and edit this answer to show examples of how your suggested solution addresses the problem.
